# Compiling problem with converter of base number

Tags: c++, hex, converters

We are suppose to write a program that that takes a number n from startBase and returns the number in endBase.

for example, if I enter ./a.out 1 ABCD 16 10
then the program should return

```
1 has 1 bit(s)
ABCD (base 16) = 43981 (base 10)
```

Below is my conversion function

```
string converter(string num, int base1, int base2){
  int decimal = 0;
  string result = "";
  if(num == "0"){
    return 0;
  }

  for(int i = num.length() - 1; i >=0; i--){
    char current = num[i];
    int e;
    if(current == 'A'||current == 'B'||current == 'C'||current == 'D'||current =='E'||current == 'F'){
      e = (int)current - 55;
    }else{
      e = (int)current - (int)'0';
    }
    decimal = decimal + e*pow(e,base1);
    }

    string strdecimal = to_string(decimal);
    while(decimal > 0){
      result = to_string(decimal%base2) + result;
      decimal = decimal/base2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is how I excuted it in the main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void outputBinary(unsigned int x);
int countBits(unsigned int n);
string converter(string num, int base1, int base2);
  

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int a = stoi(argv[1]);
  int b = countBits(a);
  string c = converter(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);
  
  cout << a << " has " << b << " bit(s)" << endl;
  cout << argv[2] << "(base" << argv[3] << ")" << "=" << c << "(base" << argv[4] << ")" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

However the following problem is encounter

```
bitCounter.cpp:15:14: error: no matching function for call to 'converter'
  string c = converter(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);
             ^~~~~~~~~
bitCounter.cpp:8:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char *' to 'int' for 2nd argument; dereference the argument with *
string converter(string num, int base1, int base2);
```

How could I fix it? Also, is my conversion function doing what it is supposed to do?
Thanks

Comment: The `argv` array is an array of strings. You pass these strings to the `converter` function without any conversion to the `int` arguments the function expect.

Comment: As for "is my conversion function doing what it is supposed to do", that's why you should learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is a (c-string) array, so you need to convert the string to `int`s. You can do this with [`std::atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).
Good luck!

Comment: It is a C function, there are other easy ways to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is a array of `char` array. So you have to convert it to `int` . So use this code:

```cpp
string c = converter(argv[2], std::stoi(argv[3]), std::stoi(argv[4]));
```

Here `std::stoi` takes `std:: string` as argument. So `char` array is converted to `std:: string` then converted to `int` . To convert to:

- `long` use `std::stol` .
- `long long` use `std::stoll` .